# find the http action in Django models.py

Tags: python, django-models, django-rest-framework

In my API (DjnagoREST framewrok), I have this model:

```
class Pet(models.Model):
    kind = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    updated_time = models.DateTimeField()
```

I am trying to change the value of the field the updated_time automatically if the http method is PUT or the http action is update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this, the `updated_time` field cet the now date each time `pet.save()` is called

```
class Pet(models.Model):
    kind = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    updated_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```